# How to specify different duration for slideUp and slideDown in jquery slideToggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slidetoggle

I want a full width panel to slide down from the top of the browser, that will display my contact details, along with social links etc:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: black;
}
.f {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip">
  <span class="f">MENU</span>
</div>
```

This works a treat, but how can I specify **different times** for slide up and slidedown?

Comment: RTD: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ It's literally the first parameter.

Comment: It's in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) quite clearly... Good luck. (Easy points up for grabs for those willing to post an answer to this one! I bet there's loads...)

Comment: BUT how can I specify DIFFERENT slide up and down times? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: In that case you'd need to determine the current state of the element and call `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` separately, providing different durations.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks. So slideToggle, only allows one speed parameter if you like?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Just edited my answer after you edited the question :)

Comment: @davvv Isn't my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store duration of animation in variable and use it. In function of callback of `slideToggle()` change duration.

```
var duration = 500;
$("#flip").click(function() {
  $("#panel").slideToggle(duration, function(){
    duration = $(this).is(":visible") ? 2000 : 500;
  });
});
```

```js
var duration = 500;
$("#flip").click(function() {
  $("#panel").slideToggle(duration, function(){
    duration = $(this).is(":visible") ? 2000 : 500;
  });
});
```

```css
#flip {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip">
  <span class="f">MENU</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I have edit my answer to reflect the change in the question.

**Use slideDown() and slideUp() instead.**

**CODEPEN**

http://codepen.io/alexincarnati/pen/PWOPjY

In case you want to add different durations to sliding up and down in jQuery then you can simply add a flag and check if the menu is opened or not and then use **slideDown()** and **slideUp()** as methods. 
That way you could add different durations to the slide.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var menuOpened = false;

  $("#flip").click(function() {

    if (menuOpened === false) {
      $("#panel").slideDown(1000, function() {
        menuOpened = true;
      });

    } else {
      $("#panel").slideUp(700, function() {
        menuOpened = false;
      });

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply just add the time as a parameter to the `slideToggle` method.

You can see in the docs this:

> slideToggle( [**duration** ] [, **complete** ] )
>
> **duration** (default: 400)
>   Type: Number or String
>   A string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> **complete**
>   Type: Function()
>   A function to call once the animation is complete, called once per matched element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle(3000);
  });
});
```

```css
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: black;
}
.f {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip">
  <span class="f">MENU</span>
</div>
```

You can read more in the official documentation **[here](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)**.

**UPDATE**:

If you want to have different durations for **[slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)** and **[slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)** methods you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var check_state = false;
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    if (check_state === false) {
      $("#panel").stop().slideDown(3000);
      check_state = true;
    } else {
      $("#panel").stop().slideUp(1500);
      check_state = false;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: black;
}
.f {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip">
  <span class="f">MENU</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks! But how can I specify different times for slide up, and a different time for slide down?

Comment: In this case you can't use `slideToggle()`, you need to use `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` separately.

Comment: @davvv, I've also updated my answer with an example using those methods. Now you can set different times.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the time in the first parameter of the function slideToggle:

```
$("#panel").slideToggle(4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read about [**.slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) on jquery documentation
As it say the `slideToggle()` function accept two parameters:

> .slideToggle( [duration ] [, complete ] )

The first is for the duration (in millisecond) and the second is the callback after the animation is complete

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle(5000 /* Here is the duration of the animation in MS */, function() {
        //Do what you want here
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#flip {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 5000;
  background-color: black;
}
.f {
  position: static;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<div id="flip">
  <span class="f">MENU</span>
</div>
```